# Wordpress/Buddypress theme has suddenly stopped working

Tags: buddypress

I am mystified because I haven't made any changes to any files on my site, haven't activated or deactivated any plugins, haven't done anything except navigate around the site, and my theme has suddenly stopped working.

When I switch to the default Buddypress theme everything seems to work, but when I activate my theme it looks as though the main style.css, which is in the same place it always is, isn't getting loaded, as the site has no styling and is completely disfigured.

You can see what I mean [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk).

I have tried to reverting to an old version of my theme and still see the issue, which suggests that it is not related to the content of my child theme folder.

I am completely stumped as to what is going on and would be glad of any help to get my site back up and running again. I have tried deactivating and reactivating my child theme, with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Your site has some issues:

1. There is no default theme stylesheet present in the page markup.  I can see several plugins loading their own styles, but none for the main `style.css`.
2. The page is broken. A view-source shows it cutting off at the bottom. There are no closing `</body>` or `</html>` tags.
3. Your server is returning a 500 Internal Server Error message along with the regular page request, so something is breaking on your server.

Unfortunately, all three of these point to some significant issues on your server and something that requires serious hands-on support.  As this is not a support site, I'm closing your question as off-topic and suggesting you ask in the [official support forums](http://wordpress.org/support) instead.  I just wanted you to have a few details for debugging first.

Comment: This is a very helpful and decent way of closing a question.